# Test data management for automation api testing

Tags: java, junit, test-data, rest-assured, api-automation

Can you help me with some ideas on how to deal more efficent with test data used as precondition for automated api tests? I can’t use api calls for creating the data, so I would have to use sql scripts. However, as every test requires quite different test data(data to be inserted in 4,5 tables; more in some cases) I don’t know how to proceed to be efficient. I will try to group somehow tests that might use same data and only run the scripts once before that group of tests and delete them after(with @before class perhaps. What are your approaches when you can t use api calls and you have to deal with large data sets? Btw, I’m using java, rest assured, junit

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSV file and put your test data in that file. Now, you can read the data from the CSV file and use it in your test case.

Create a CSV file with your test data. I am using the following as an example:

```
Name,Emp Id,Department
abc,123,xyz
```

You can modify the data in your CSV file according to your test requirements.

Use the following code as a reference:

```
public class YourTestClass {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/your_data_file.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
    // Assuming your CSV file is in the resources directory and the first line contains headers
    
    public void testMethod(String name, int empId, String department) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", Emp Id: " + empId + ", Department: " + department);
        // Add your assertions or test logic here
        // For example:
        assertEquals("xyz", department);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a large list of test data, you can use a CSV parsing library to read the data from the file and store it in a map. Below is an example:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestDataLoader {

    public static Map<String, Object[]> loadTestData(String filePath) {
        Map<String, Object[]> testDataMap = new HashMap<>();

        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String[] headers = reader.readNext(); // Assuming the first line contains headers

            String[] nextLine;
            int index = 0;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                Object[] rowData = new Object[headers.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                    rowData[i] = nextLine[i];
                }
                testDataMap.put("Test" + index++, rowData);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle the exception according to your requirements
        }

        return testDataMap;
    }
}
```

Use the map in your JUnit test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class YourTestClass {

    private String name;
    private int empId;
    private String department;

    // Constructor to receive the parameters
    public YourTestClass(String name, int empId, String department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        // Your test logic using the parameters
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", Emp Id: " + empId + ", Department: " + department);

        // Add your assertions or test logic here
        // For example:
        assertEquals("xyz", department);
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Map<String, Object[]> data() {
        String filePath = "path/to/testdata.csv"; // Update with the actual path
        return TestDataLoader.loadTestData(filePath);
    }
}
```

With this approach, there is no need to hard-code test data within the code or scripts. Test data can be easily updated in the CSV file whenever any changes occur.